# How to display one set of data between two models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-templates

I have Model Question and Answer.
What I want to accomplish is to be able to display it in the template in a way that shows like this. I would like to know a way to accomplish this. I'm trying my best to not let it loop the whole data in a model but rather one data at a time. I'm trying to make a qna data and make it display on a template. so having all the Questio data displayed before Answer data is not what I want. It has to be one by one for these two models. I'm getting kinda close...but I stil can't figure out how to accomplish this. Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Q.title

Q.body

A.body

Q.title

Q.body

A.body

Q.title

Q.body

A.body

modesl.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.utils import timezone

class Question(models.Model):
    title= models.CharField(max_length= 100)
    body= models.TextField()
    date_posted= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Answer(models.Model):
    body= models.TextField()
    question= models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete= models.CASCADE)
    date_posted= models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    author= models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete= models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.body
```

qna.html template

```
{% extends "info/base.html" %}
{% block content %}

{% for question in questions %}
        <h1> Q</h1>
        <h3> {{ question.title }} </h3>
  {% for answer in answers %}
    <h1> A </h1> 
    <h3> {{ answer.body }}</h3>
  {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}




{% endblock content %}
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Question, Answer

def qna(request):
    context= {
        'questions': Question.objects.all(),
        'answers': Answer.objects.all(),
    }
    return render(request, 'qna/qna.html', context)
```

Comment: Is it possible having multiple answers for a single question?

Comment: @Jafoor I want only one answer per question. The design is to only have one admin answer all the question. this is a small app so i intend for it to work that way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Answer model has relation of ForeignKey with question you can directly access question model fields in reverse.Replace your code in html like below and check if same works for you.

```
{% extends "info/base.html" %}
{% block content %}
{% for answer in answers %}
        <h1> Question:</h1>
        <h3> title:  {{ answer.question.title }} </h3>
        <h3> body: {{ answer.question.body }} </h3>
        <h1> Answer: </h1><h3> {{ answer.body }} </h3>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: This works perfectly!!!! I was searching to do something like this!! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @Kentypop: Glad to hear that :) Iam also learning and i know there are other best ways to achieve it but  i think this fits in as per your code.

Comment: I'm sorry to bother you. But my brain cant seems to wrap around WHY my previous piece of code is loopping all the Answer data, but ur code works in a way that it only extract one data at a time?

Comment: It loops all the answer because you have placed a loop to iterate all answers within a question loop. When you try to access first question from question queryset by {% for question in questions %} line and then within that iteration you again placed a loop to iterate all answers one by one {% for answer in answers %}.So what happens is on each iteration for question you are iterating all answers.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!! Its so clear to me now. Have a good day, stay safe!

Answer (score 2):

Add `related_name` to model `Answer` that has `ForeignKey` with `Question`:

`question= models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete= models.CASCADE, related_name='my_answes')`

in HTML file replace the second loop with :

```
{% for answer in question.my_answes.all %}
   <h1> A </h1> 
   <h3> {{ answer.body }}</h3>
   <hr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you!! I didnt know related_name exist ! apprecfiate it!